# Using vagrant to isolate my whole environment

Tags: vagrant

I want to use Vagrant to isolate my whole development environment from my system (OS X 10.9.3), and not just for a specific software project. Is Vagrant a right tool for this task, or there are better options? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vagrant is, at its core, a way to quickly and reproducibly fire up virtual machines. There's no requirement to tie it to a single software project. Setting up a development environment for more than one project will work just fine.